# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}dx$ converges $\iff n$ is even

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'd like to show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}dx \text{ converges} \iff n\text{ is even.}$$

---

*My attempt:*

Suppose $n$ is odd. Then $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}dx+\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{x^n}dx}_{\text{diverges}}$$ The second integral diverges since $e^{x^n}\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

If instead, $n$ is even, then $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}dx =2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^n}dx$$
I don't know how to show this is bounded.

---

I would like to know if there is any inequality I can use to bound this, and show that the integral is finite.

Comment: If it's odd, then $-x^n$ is positive as $x \to -\infty$, hence $\exp(-x^n)$ gets really big, so divergence. If $n$ is even, then by symmetry it suffices to show $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^n}  \ dx$ converges, which is fairly clear.

Comment: You might want to show that since $x^n>x$ for sufficiently large $x,$ then $e^{-x^n}<e^{-x},$ and showing that the latter converges will give you a bound.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Unfortunately this "fairly clear" part is where I struggled...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $x^n \le e^{x^n}$, so $\frac1{x^n}\ge e^{-x^n}$. With $f(x) = e^{-x^n}$, write:

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx + \int_1^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

The first integral on the RHS is obviously convergent. The second integral converges by comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Clearly, $e^{x^4} > e^{x^2}$ so
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{x^4}} < \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{x^2}} = J
$$
and RHS is computable exactly since
$$
J^2 = \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{e^{x^2}}\right)
      \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{dy}{e^{y^2}}\right)
    = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{dxdy}{e^{x^2+y^2}}
    = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{rdr}{e^{r^2}}
$$
which is now trivially integratable.

Comment: $e^{x^4}>e^{x^2}$ is only valid for $|x|>1$, but yes, this is quite easy to modify, and still works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$0\le\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}\mathrm dx\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k^n}$$

Applying the root test we have that

$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{e^{-k^n}}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}e^{-k^{(n-1)}}=0,\quad n>1$$